# Matlab not recognizing string variable

Tags: matlab

I have a variable that is holding a string (the string contains a path to a .mat file). However whenever I call load the variable I get an error saying "Error using load Unable to read file"

Here is my code where I call load:

```
fName = strcat(fName,'_features.mat');
display(fName);
load(fName);
```

For those curious fName = '/Users/MATLAB/10360453085_p2_features.mat'

Why am getting an error on load even though when I copy the value of fName into load it works perfectly fine, but using load(fName) gives me an error?

Comment: What is the value of `fName`, before execution of `strcat`?

Comment: It comes from an array that contains a list of paths. The array is declared as follows: `imnames = {}`

Comment: I ask because you use `fName` to create an `fName`. Are you sure that value of `fName` before `strcat` is correct?

Comment: @user2604504: can you tell us  the exact error message?

Comment: He does display it and says it's correct. Isn't there a drive letter missing though? Then again, in that case, manually copying the value into `load` shouldn't work either.

Comment: does the file really exist? post the output of: `exist(fName,'file')` and: `whos(fName)`

Comment: So fName comes from  `fName = strrep(imnames_train(i),'.png', '');` and `imnames_train(i)` is initialized as `imnames_train{}`. Also when I do `exist (fName, 'file')` the output says "Undefined function 'exist' for input arguments of type 'cell'. I'm thinking that because imnames is declared as a cell array it's not being recognized as a string. How would I change fName from a cell array to a string?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, `fname` is initialized somewhere as a cell array. `strcat` will therefore return a cell array, so that `disp` will display it as `'name'` rather than `name`.

```
load(fName{1})
```

or

```
load(char(fName))
```

will work in this case.

Comment: That wouldn't create a "Unable to read file" error though - as far as I know.

Comment: @Sebastian: yes, you're right. There may be multiple problems here.